# how to solve read timeout on redis?

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm the new to Redis. In my case, there is a project A insert data to redis maybe 10000 records per second. And I have project B to read data from redis to mongodb in every 5 minutes.By the way , both project is coding by java.

Project A will work normally, but project B will throw read timeout exception. It due to Project B need to get all keys of redis that maybe very large about 4 millions.So I use command:

```
keys *
```

and it will read timeout. By the way, I also try the command about `scan`, but it too slow.I want to ask how to set the configure about timeout? maybe I need to

`timeout = 5 minutes`

How to do it? Have any better solve to my this case?

Comment: "Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases" http://redis.io/commands/KEYS. You should consider using Hashes or Sets.

Comment: @thepirat000 but how can I get the all keys in redis? Scan is too slow.

Comment: Your have a bad application design. try to 'rethink' it.
For example you may try to use redis [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications).
Your application B must subscribe for that chanels, for example
$ redis-cli psubscribe '__keyevent@0__:set'
and you will get all the keys are seted after your subscription. And so on...